# Shortcut key for switching between split panes

Tags: visual-studio-code

I see that <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>\</kbd> will create a new 'pane' in VS Code. Is there a way to switch between open panes using only the keyboard?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

You can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd> (<kbd>Cmd</kbd> on Mac) to navigate between up to three opened panes.

Comment: Fun fact, Ctrl+1, 2, etc. on a mac will switch between the open tabs in that selected window.

Comment: You can set your own keybinding by going to Keyboard Shortcuts --> Focus First Editor Group (workbench.action.focusFirstEditorGroup), focusSecond, focusThird, ... etc @BrittanMcGinnis

Answer (score 19):

If you happen to use the vim extension, insert below setting into the `keybindings.json`[*cmd/ctrl+shift+p*, then typeahead `open keyboard shortcuts(JSON)`]. This should give you familiar experience as in vim/neovim to navigate bewteen panes.

```
    {
        "key": "ctrl+j",
        "command": "workbench.action.navigateDown",
        "when": "vim.mode != 'Insert'"
    },
    {
        "key": "ctrl+k",
        "command": "workbench.action.navigateUp",
        "when": "vim.mode != 'Insert'"
    },
    {
        "key": "ctrl+h",
        "command": "workbench.action.navigateLeft",
        "when": "vim.mode != 'Insert'"
    },
    {
        "key": "ctrl+l",
        "command": "workbench.action.navigateRight",
        "when": "vim.mode != 'Insert'"
    }
```

Comment: Wouldn't the "real" VIm feel be to type Ctrl-W in command mode and _then_ these letters without `ctrl` before them to swap windows?